# 3d surface reconstruction using openCV examples

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to perform a 3D surface reconstruction from a stereo configuration with OpenCV example files. I have created a stereo camera from 2 web cams. I have obtained the calibration parameters using stereo_calib.cpp ( https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stereo_calib.cpp?rev=4086 ) and generated a point cloud with stereo_match.cpp ( https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/stereo_match.cpp?rev=2614 ). The resulting point cloud, opened with MeshLab doesn't resemble the original scene at all ( http://img707.imageshack.us/i/snapshot01u.png/ ).

What am I missing here?

Steps to recreate:

1. stereo_calib (on the same folder where the images are, with no arguments so it assumes default)
2. stereo_match left01.jpg right01.jpg -i intrinsics.yml -e extrinsics.yml -p cloud.asc
3. import cloud.asc on MeshLab

Thanks

Comment: This looks very much like the camera calibration messed up. Did you use your own images/cameras? Most likely calibration failed.